# how to find a point coordinates having it's start point, width and angle related to X

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, geometry, 2d

how can I find the position of the red dot?

I want to find x, y of that RED dot...

I want to do this in javascript, for canvas, I want to draw a line starting from a certain point and in one direction (and I have the angle)...

[image]

do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Math-wise, if r is what you're calling "width", and ø is the angle, then:

x = r * cos(ø)

y = r * sin(ø)

I don't know JavaScript, so how you'd code this in that language is left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: forgot to tell you.. it worked :) thank you a lot... a small mention here... the angle must not be degrees...

Comment: @Ales: When using trig functions, whether an angle must be in degrees or radians depends on the implementation. I didn't know about JavaScript's implementation.

Comment: ok. thank you. it worked :) it was in radians. in degrees is somehow else... regards